# How do I install this Visual Studio project template?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, github

I can't for the life of me figure this out. The "how to" video shows two .zip files in the ProjectTemplates/Visual C# folder, but I can't find them on this GitHub page... the instructions say under the "downloads tab up above ... download both of the project templates" and I can't even find the tab or the download option for the zip files seen in the video.

Here's what I've tried:

- downloaded the single .zip file that contains both projects and put that .zip in the ProjectTemplates/Visual C# folder. Restart VS2010 - New Project, I don't see it as an option
- Zipped the nested project, put that in the same folder as above. Restart VS2010 - New Project, but it's not an option

There is no .msi or .vsix file in the download.

Any help is appreciated

https://github.com/irobinson/WebFormsMvp-DNN-Module-Template

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The downloads tab that the instructions refer to doesn't exist any longer, which probably explains why you're having trouble finding it.

Luckily, you can still find the downloads here: https://github.com/irobinson/WebFormsMvp-DNN-Module-Template/downloads

Once you've downloaded those and added the zips to your templates folder, you should be good to go.

Comment: That did it. Call me crazy, but if the point is to download code/templates/projects etc, shouldn't they have a download link or button? Did you have to type "/downloads" into your browser?

Comment: Github used to allow you to upload a prepackaged download, in many cases a binary. Since you are also able to download a repo, this led to some confusion. Github is therefore [transitioning away from allowing separate downloads](https://github.com/blog/1302-goodbye-uploads), part of which is removing the download link. This change is recent and that repo has not been updated recently. Ideally, it would be possible to hit the `zip` button to get a working package in this case, but it sounds like some modifications would be required to get that working. -- Yes, I appended `/downloads`.